# How can I trigger the minlength validation when field is set programmatically?

Tags: html, forms, validation

I have a field inside of a form like this:

```
<input type="text" minlength="20" name="description" id="description" />
```

When typed into, the `minlength` validation works great. But if the input's value is set programmatically the validation won't trigger.

```
var field = document.querySelector("#description");

// type a couple of character into the field
field.validity.tooShort;
// true

field.value = '';
field.validity.tooShort;
// false
```

Is there a workaround for this? Or a planned fix? Am I using it wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by programmatically like creating an element description programmatically using JQuery ?

Comment: I don't know why it's not working but as a workaround you can do it manually, get the attribute and the length of the value and compare them

Comment: Another workaround would be to use a pattern, something like this: `pattern=".{20,}"`

Comment: @BASEERHAIDER I mean like setting the value without typing in the field. `field.value = "some text"`

Comment: @EdwardLoveall so you want something like that if you do something like this field.value = "some text" and your field has min length 5 so it should show an error. is that true ?

Comment: @EdwardLoveall can you please provide some code so that I get some idea what actually you are looking for because I am not clear about your requirement.

Comment: Right, I think the code above demonstrates it. You can play with it here: https://s.codepen.io/edwardloveall/debug/yPKVzW Open up the console and type in the code I have in the question line by line, and you'll see field validation be false even when there are less than 20 character in the input.

Answer (score 1):

Stumbled across this today, you can work around it with `pattern` validation:

```
<input type="text" pattern="^.{20,}$" name="description" id="description" />
```

JS:

```
var field = document.querySelector("#description");
field.value = 'too short';
field.validity.patternMismatch;
// true

field.value = 'very very very very very very long';
field.validity.patternMismatch;
// false
```

Answer (score -2):

You can force the validation process by using

```
field.checkValidity();
```

See [MSDN about checkValidity()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/checkValidity)

This page is about select but it's of course valid for every input field.

**EDIT** : My bad, this is not working, you should do the validation manually.

Comment: Not working, this returns true when it should return false, check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/noshq2kw/1)

Comment: This can only be used to verify `required`, and will always return` true` when `disabled = true`