# HTML input checkValidity() always returns true even with minlength violations

Tags: html

Pretty simple set up:

```js
const input = window.document.getElementById('Input');
input.value = "foobar"
console.log(input.checkValidity());
```

```html
<input id="Input" type="text" minlength="8" required />
```

The following returns `true` when it should be `false`. See https://jsbin.com/huqowesewu/edit?html,output

Why in the world is this? The input has a length of 6, which is less than 8, ergo, it should be invalid. But it's not. Is this attribute broken? Or is `checkValidity()` broken? I'm baffled to say the least.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This should work. As per WHATWG it should work. As per caniuse.com it should work.

However, it appears to only work when the value was edited by the user, not set from JavaScript. <strike>I did not find anything on WHATWG or MDN regarding that behavior (perhaps it is there, and I don't know where to look).</strike>

It is documented on WHATWG. Both `minlength` and `maxlength` require user interaction. To be more precise, when the user modifies the input value a "dirty value flag" is set, which is taken into account in the validation. See [Limiting user input length: the maxlength attribute](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#setting-minimum-input-length-requirements:-the-minlength-attribute):

> **Constraint validation**: If an element has a minimum allowed value length, its **dirty value flag** is true, **its value was last changed by a user edit (as opposed to a change made by a script)**, its value is not the empty string, and the length of the element's API value is less than the element's minimum allowed value length, then the element is suffering from being too short.

---

Things I tested but do not make it work: Listening to the `"invalid"` event. Triggering an `"input"` event. Removing focus from the `input` with `blur()` before checking. Checking from `queueMicrotask(function)`. Checking from `requestAnimationFrame(function)`. Checking from double `requestAnimationFrame(function)`. Checking with a valid value and then checking with an invalid value. Setting either a valid or an non-empty invalid default value via HTML attribute. Setting the value with `setAttribute` from JavaScript. Setting `defaultValue`.

I tested on Chromium Edge and Firefox.

I also found the question [How can I trigger the minlength validation when field is set programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47417563/how-can-i-trigger-the-minlength-validation-when-field-is-set-programmatically) which provided no solution.

---

Anyway, you can use `pattern` to mimic this validation constraint. And yes, that one will trigger from JavaScript correctly, as most validation constraints do. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/10294291/402022

Comment: Ah, okay, glad I'm not doing something horribly wrong. I came across `pattern` which I swapped to but I really wanted to know why this wasn't working. Broken spec is beyond my control though. Thanks for all your time.

Comment: @Devildude4427 found and added the spec.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your efforts @Devildude4427 
I've been testing it for hours to understand what I've done wrong. Seems like it's not a bug, it's a feature...

Answer (score -1):

This is a better way to get false.

```js
function myfunction() {
  var iny = document.getElementById("Input");
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = iny.checkValidity();
}
```

```html
<input type="text" minlength="8" id="Input" required />
<button onclick="myfunction()">TRY</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: That'll still return `true` when it should `false`. All you're doing is moving the console log into the DOM.

Comment: Change function to this:                                                                                            function myfunction(){
      var iny = document.getElementById("Input");
       console.log(iny.checkValidity());
    }

Comment: You're forgetting to set the input content. You need to do that or your "solution" is just ignoring the problem.

Comment: The `required` constraint works. The issue is with `minlength`. We, of course, use them together because if the input is not required, it does not have to be valid. To reiterate, when the `input` is empty, we get `false` as expected. For which `required` is sufficient. But when the `input` is not empty, but its contents is shorter than `minlength` we get `true`, meaning that `minlength` wasn't checked. We of course want `false` in that situation. To reiterate again, we want `false` when the `input` is not empty and its contents is shorter than `minlength`.