# HTML input validity initial state

Tags: javascript, html, validation, input, checkvalidity

Let me show some examples so you understand the problem clearly.

### ✔️ Exemple 1 : working as expected

Consider an input `<input required />` and some css to visualize his validity.

```js
console.log( document.querySelector('input').checkValidity() )
```

```css
input:invalid { background: pink; }
```

```html
<input required />
```

If we check it's validity state via Javascript `inputEl.checkValidity()` we get a `false`, looking further in `inputEl.validity` shows `{ valueMissing: true, typeMismatch: false, …}`

Ok everything is logic for now.

### ✔️ Exemple 2 : working as expected

Now if we add a value to the input, validation should be fine :

```js
console.log( document.querySelector('input').checkValidity() )
```

```css
input:invalid { background: pink; }
```

```html
<input required value="John Cena" />
```

If we check it's validity state via Javascript `inputEl.checkValidity()` we get a `true`.

Make sense.

### ❌ Exemple 3 : not working as expected

Let's add `maxlength="5"` :

```js
console.log( document.querySelector('input').checkValidity() )
```

```css
input:invalid { background: pink; }
```

```html
<input required value="John Cena" maxlength="5" />
```

Why is the field not invalid initially ?

If we check it's validity state via Javascript `inputEl.checkValidity()` we get a `true` ... ?

Also if we edit this input, then the validation will be updated and the field will be marked as invalid.

Here is the full exemple : https://codepen.io/Shuunen/pen/XWaqpVo

Comment: thanks for the edit, exemple 3 should return false IMHO because value is longer than 5

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTML input checkValidity() always returns true even with minlength violations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66896018/html-input-checkvalidity-always-returns-true-even-with-minlength-violations)

Comment: No you have to use a `pattern` attribute to check that

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10281962/is-there-a-minlength-validation-attribute-in-html5/10294291#10294291 your answer

Comment: the pattern is ` pattern=".{0,5}"`

Comment: You are right, switching from `maxlength` to `pattern` does trigger the inital validity state correctly, thanks <3