# How to trigger HTML5 form validation on input

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I have a form like this. The value comes from the database, and the user should fix the problem that keeps it from validating.

```
<style> input:invalid {border: 3px solid red} </style>
<form>
    <input type="text" id="name" maxlength="10" value="A very very long name !">
</form>
```

I would expect that the input field is `:invalid`, but it isn't. `input.checkValidity()` and `form.reportValidity()` both return `true`.

Once I edit the field (delete a character), the field becomes invalid, and the javascript functions return `false` as expected.

How can I trigger the HTML validation through Javascript, instead of through user interaction?

Comment: Please include how you are calling `input.checkValidity()` and `form.reportValidity()`.

Comment: To quote [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66896481/519413) in the duplicate: `It is documented on WHATWG. Both minlength and maxlength require user interaction. To be more precise, when the user modifies the input value a "dirty value flag" is set, which is taken into account in the validation.`

Comment: I'm also wondering under what circumstances one would start with an invalid value?